# Endless scrolling gridview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm looking for a gridview which has a potentially endless scroll, ie a uitableview but with a grid, to put icons on the same way you might on the Android app drawer, or the photos app. As far as i'm aware there isn't any functionality to create a gridview on the iPhone. Are there any open source projects for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I researched this quite recently for a project that needed a grid view. These are the components I found:

1. https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView - My personal preference.
2. https://github.com/provideal/MMGridView
3. https://github.com/danielctull/DTGridView

If you decide to create one yourself I would follow how a few of the components do it and use a similar API to that of UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but the basis of it is going to be creating a custom view with UIImageViews, and then pulling that into a UIScrollVIew. You can do this custom, or utilize some of the options already available. Try checking out Three20 at:

https://github.com/facebook/three20

That's a great starting place for an app that's ready for you. Even if you prefer a custom solution, it makes a great reference.